# Why are the cylindrical and spherical electrode potential equations different from each other?

Tags: high-voltage, electrode

There isn't any information about the calculus performed to find these equations but the book says: One dimensional Laplace equation for the cylindrical coordinates depending on the variable "r" is:\$\frac{d^2V}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\cdot\frac{dV}{dr}=0\$. The general solution for this Laplace equation is:\$V=A+B \cdot lnr\$
For the spherical electrodes, we solved a very similar Laplace equation which is:\$\frac{d^2V}{dr^2}+\frac{2}{r}\cdot\frac{dV}{dr}=0\$

According to the book, the general solution for this Laplace equation is:\$V=A+\frac{B}{r}\$.

How come these two equations, despite being so similar (only a constant is changing from 1 to 2,) can produce two very different solutions? Does it have something to do with the cylindrical and spherical coordinates having different formulas for the Laplace equations?

Answer (score 0):

Not really something to do with "coordinates",
but with the "volume" where these equations are applied :

- "cylindrical" ... as "transmission lines" where we see \$ln(r)\$ functions,
- and "spherical" which is really "different" and where we see functions as \$1/r\$, \$1/r^2\$ or more.